# ReduxToolkit how to pass custom error from API into CreateAsync thunk and CreateReducer

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I want to display custom error from API request but I completely don't know how to do this via redux toolkit.
Below you can see the example.

API:

```js
auth = async (payload) => {
  return await this.api.post(payload)
}
```

action:

```js
 export const auth = createAsyncThunk('api/auth', async (payload) => {
   const response = await api.auth(payload)
   if (response.status != 200) {
     return response.data
   }
 })
```

reducer:

```js
export default createReducer(initialState, builder => builder.addCase(auth.rejected, (state, action) => {
  state.error = action.error.message // here I want to set API error response
}))
```

The problem is that I don't know how to pass error message from API to reducer `action.error.message` - is serializedError as default

Comment: Is what you have now not working?  `SerializedError` does have a `message` property (though it's optional).  Is your api including a message in its errors?

Comment: You are looking for `rejectWithValue` - take a look at the api docs for `createAsyncThunk` :)

Comment: @phry yup I was looking exactly for this, but I didn't know how to use it in the proper way :D thanks